# Probabilities from cross_val_predict using RepeatedStratifiedKFold 5*10

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, roc, k-fold

My Goal is to calculate the AUC, Specificity, Sensitivity with 95 % CI from a 5*10 StratifiedKfold CV. I also need the Specificity and Sensitivity for a Threshold of 0.4 to maximize the Sensitivity.

So far I was able to implement it for the AUC. Code below:

```
seed = 42

# Grid Search
fit_intercept=[True, False]
C = [np.arange(1,41,1)]
penalty = ['l1', 'l2']

params = dict(C=C, fit_intercept = fit_intercept, penalty = penalty)
print(params)

 logreg = LogisticRegression(random_state=seed)
# instantiate the grid
logreg_grid = GridSearchCV(logreg, param_grid = params , cv=5, scoring='roc_auc',  iid='False')
# fit the grid with data
logreg_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

logreg = logreg_grid.best_estimator_

cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits = 5, n_repeats = 10, random_state = seed)


logreg_scores = cross_val_score(logreg, X_train, y_train, cv=cv, scoring='roc_auc')
print('LogReg:',logreg_scores.mean())


import scipy.stats
def mean_confidence_interval(data, confidence=0.95):
    a = 1.0 * np.array(data)
    n = len(a)
    m, se = np.mean(a), scipy.stats.sem(a)
    h = se * scipy.stats.t.ppf((1 + confidence) / 2, n-1)
    return m, m-h, m+h

mean_confidence_interval(logreg_scores, confidence=0.95)
```

Output: (0.7964761904761904, 0.7675441789148183, 0.8254082020375626)

I am really satisfied so far, but how can I implement this for the probabilities, so I can calculate the FPR, TPR and the Thresholds? 
For a simple 5-fold I would do it like this:

```
def evaluate_threshold(threshold):
    print('Sensitivity(',threshold,'):', tpr[thresholds > threshold][-1])
    print('Specificity(',threshold,'):', 1 - fpr[thresholds > threshold][-1])

logreg_proba = cross_val_predict(logreg, X_train, y_train, cv=5, method='predict_proba')
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_train, log_proba[:,1])
evaluate_threshold(0.5)
evaluate_threshold(0.4)

#Output would be: 
#Sensitivity( 0.5 ): 0.76
#Specificity( 0.5 ): 0.7096774193548387
#Sensitivity( 0.4 ): 0.88
#Specificity( 0.4 ): 0.6129032258064516
```

If I try it this way with the 5*10 CV:

```
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits = 5, n_repeats = 10, random_state = seed)    
y_pred = cross_val_predict(logreg, X_train, y_train, cv=cv, method='predict_proba')
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_train, log_proba[:,1])
evaluate_threshold(0.5)
evaluate_threshold(0.4)
```

it throws an error:

```
cross_val_predict only works for partitions
```

Can you help me to solve this please?

Answer (score 1):

That is what I have tried.

```
for i in range(10):
    cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 5, random_state = i)   
    y_pred = cross_val_predict(logreg, X_train, y_train, cv=cv, method='predict_proba')
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_train, log_proba[:,1])
    evaluate_threshold(0.5)

Out: 
Sensitivity( 0.5 ): 0.84
Specificity( 0.5 ): 0.6451612903225806
Sensitivity( 0.5 ): 0.84
Specificity( 0.5 ): 0.6451612903225806
Sensitivity( 0.5 ): 0.84
Specificity( 0.5 ): 0.6451612903225806
and so on....
```

Unfortunately the output is always the same and is not what I would expect when using RepeatedStratifiedKFold.

Maybe someone can give me an advice?